# ViewModel не принимает QueryProperty

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

При срабатывании `Command` должна открываться страница, при этом на ее ViewModel должна посылаться модель, проблема в том, что метод `ApplyQueryAttributes` внутри ViewModel'a принимателя не срабатывает (или как-то неправильно принимает)

Инициализация открытия страницы:

```
OpenDialog = new Command<object>(async (object message) =>
        {
            var msg = message as Models.Visual.MessageInPrivateChats;
            Models.Dialog Dialog = new Models.Dialog()
            {
                Title = msg.Title,
                DialogID = msg.DialogID,
                Type = Constants.Server.DIALOG_TYPE_PRIVATE
            };


            Debug.WriteLine($"Dialog sended: {Dialog.Title}", "PrivateChatsViewModel");
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("chats/ChatForm", true, new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["Dialog"] = Dialog
            });

        });
```

Получение данных:

```
public partial class ChatFormViewModel : BaseViewModel, IQueryAttributable
    {
        public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            Dialog = query["Dialog"] as Models.Dialog;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Dialog responsed: {Dialog.Title}", "ChatFormViewModel"); //строки нет в Debug'e
            OnPropertyChanged("Dialog");
        }
```

Исключение `NullReference` ссылается на строку:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"dialog responsed: {Dialog.Title}", "ChatFormViewModel");
```

Внутри конструктора класса `ViewModel`, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо

Comment: Вот это что за ужас? `Command<object>` Почему `object` а не сразу конкретный тип? Все ваши конвертации - это костыль, который вы сами себе придумали. Касательно ошибки, ну, логинчо наверо предположить, что `Dialig` у вас `NULL`. Почему? Наверно потому, что `query["Dialog"]` не является `Models.Dialog`. Почему? А тут уже известно только вам что там за `object`. Ставьте точку остановки, запускайте, смотрите что в словаре, потом думайте как это туда попало. И да `OnPropertyChanged("Dialog");` тоже костыль, ибо это должно быть в `Set` свойства.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю! а подскажите, пожалуйста, как этот словарь открыть?

Comment: В каком плане открыть? Отладка? Сбоку, где нумерация строк, наведите мышь  возле проблемной строки, там можно будет поставить красный кружок, ставьте его - это точка остановки, когда ваш код добежит до нее, студия должна будет остановить все и показать данные, дальше просто наводите мышью на нужные значения и смотрите что там у них, какие типы, и так далее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, нашел, спасибо)

Comment: Тогда если вопрос неактуален, то удалите его, либо напишите ответ. Помните, SO это не форум, а база интересных вопросов и ответов на них, которые интересны не только вам, но и будущим читателям. Зачем базе вопрос, который интересен только вам, да и на который только вы можете дать ответ, верно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, согласен, но ответ я пока еще ищу)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подскажите, пожалуйста, я вот через точки останова посмотрел, при отправке `Dialog` заполненный, при инициализации конструктора класса  `ChatFormViewModel` тот же Dialog равен null, такое ощущение, как будто для срабатывания `ApplyQueryAttributes` нужно что-то где-то дополнительно прописать, есть в этом необходимость?

Comment: Честно, без понятия. Я не работаю с MAUI, считая его еще очень сырым для реализации на нем каких-либо из своих проектов. Почитав документацию, я увидел там примеры с [использованием атрибута](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes), как по мне весьма удобные, чем брать из словаря, попробуйте этот подход, а не наследование от `IQueryAttributable`. Ну и да, `ChatFormViewModel` должна быть задана как `BindingContext`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я попробовал, ничего не изменилось. Проблема в том, что страница эта открывалась (данные приходили при помощи именно наследования), потом я внес изменения во ViewModel - отправитель, которые никак не затрагивали действие команды и как-то всё сломалось, в общем, пока чинил одно, сломалось другое :D